# Ед. или мн. число?

Tags: орфография

Персонал в целом и каждый сотрудник в отдельности долЖЕН(-жны)??? иметь высокую степень доверия к руководителю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, уместнее будет сказать все-таки "должен". Потому что и персонал - это "он", и сотрудник - тоже "он". Так выйдет, что слово "должен" относится и к тому, и к другому слову. Потому что "должны" все-таки как-то не звучит.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта. Обычно при однородных подлежащих с соединительным союзом сказуемое в постпозиции ставится во множественном числе, но это не строгое требование.

Answer (score 0):

Верно: должен. Сказуемое согласуется с подлежащем в числе и в роде. У вас подлежащее в ед.ч. Поэтому и сказуемое в ед.ч.